# Limit Upload Bandwidth for each user in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, upload, bandwidth, bandwidth-throttling

i want to limit upload bandwidth in IIS. my scenario is each user only can upload 300kbps.

i check `MaxBandwidth` in IIS but it limit for sum of users not for each user.
also i check `Throttling Bandwidth` but it limit download bandwidth.

so how can i limit upload bandwidth for each user or each file in IIS?

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot impose a bandwidth limit on single thread (single connection) to your website in IIS.
Instead you can use something like this, for max-connections

```
   <limits maxBandwidth="65536"
         maxConnections="1024"
         connectionTimeout="00:01:00" />
```

Please check the below URL :

http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/site/limits

To Limit the upload please check the below URL :

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/942074

Comment: thank you for your reply. in my test 'maxBandwidth' don't limit upload. so how can i limit upload in iis?